How to Implement a "Forgot Password" Feature in Flask without Sending Actual Emails?
I'm working on a hotel booking website for a semester project using Flask and Python. My professor pointed out that our login system lacks a "Forgot Password" feature, which needs to be implemented.The problem is that we're using fake email IDs for user accounts (e.g., testuser@example.com), so there's no real email associated with these accounts. Since we're not sending actual confirmation links, I'm unsure how to implement the "Forgot Password" feature effectively.
I thought of implementing security questions, but thought of doing other more reliable techniques.

That kind of feature often (if not always) requires some kind of personal property of user that can be safely used to communicate with user. In this example to provide him with new password or link where he can safely change password. What you can do is try to use temporary emails and use email sending provider to send real emails. It will be good practice for you. Instead of temporary emails, you can use Google's email append feature: https://gmail.googleblog.com/2008/03/2-hidden-ways-to-get-more-from-your.html

To satisfy the requirement even though you are using fake/mock generated e-mails, you could build the mechanism front-end request password page and backend match to user and fire an e-mail; I think the professor might want you to demonstrate the capability regardless of the e-mails not being accurate; additionally, you can consider adding a field for mobile and using SMS, or 2 security questions + username combo to get the pass; something along those lines
